# how to get indexof(object) in android please see my example for understand

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Please read this example for understand my problem, thanks.

After adding some data to arraylist like this:

```
ArrayList<UserInfo> user_info = new ArrayList<>();
user_info.add(new UserInfo(1, "alex", "26"));
user_info.add(new UserInfo(2, "daniel", "23"));
user_info.add(new UserInfo(3, "veka", "19"));
```

I want to get index of **"veka"**, how i can do it ?
I know how to do it with array string using get index of, but how i can do it using my example with **UserInfo**

Thanks.

this is **UserInfo.class**

```
public class UserInfo {

private int id;
private String UserName;
private String UserAge;

public UserInfo(int id, String userName, String userAge) {
    this.id = id;
    UserName = userName;
    UserAge = userAge;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return UserName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    UserName = userName;
}

public String getUserAge() {
    return UserAge;
}

public void setUserAge(String userAge) {
    UserAge = userAge;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the override the `equals` method. This will be used by the `indexOf` function.

An example is here

```
public class Point {

    int x; 
    int y;

    public Point(int a, int b) {
    this.x=a;this.y=b;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Point other = (Point) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }       
}

ArrayList<Point> p=new ArrayList<Point>();

Point p1 = new Point(3,4);
Point p2 = new Point(1,2);

p.add(new Point(3,4));
p.add(new Point(1,2));

System.out.println(p.indexOf(p1));
```

With this information you can update your class and then it will work.

Comment: thanks, i need index for value because i have recyclerview with image and other viewtype, i add all images in arraylist, then i pass this array to viewpager adapter, my problem is i need the id was clicked for show first image correctly,  know the image url was clicked, i need only id for pass to view pager using setCurrentItem(id), any idea

Answer (score 0):

Is there a certain reason behind the fact that are you using ArrayList instead of Hashmap? Hashmap provides a quick lookup by a certain key (It could be your UserName)

Pseudocode would look something like this:

`HashMap<String, UserInfo> info = new Hashmap<>();
info.add("A", new UserInfo(1, "A", "26");
info.add("B", new UserInfo(2, "B", "26");
info.add("C", new UserInfo(3, "C", "26");`

and then a simple info.get("A") would return you UserInfo(2, "B", "26").

But if there's a need for an Arraylist, then iterating through the whole array and checking if the provided UserName matches the UserInfo's object's Username. PseudoCode is once again here:

You add a new method in ArrayList:

`public void isMatchingUsername(String userName) { return this.UserName == username; }`

and then just:

```
UserInfo matchingUser;
for(UserInfo userInfo : user_info){
    if(userInfo.isMatchingUsername("theUsersUsername")){
        machingUser = userInfo;
        break;
    }
}`
```

And there you have it - matchingUser has a reference to the UserInfo that you wanted to find

Comment: i have an ViewPager based on this arraylist, and i need this id for set Current Item after click, i use recyclerView with 3 ViewType, so i can't use recyclerView item position because position in recyclerView different from arraylist, i dont know id, but i can get the user name that clicked, i have used 3 arrayString id, name, age. then use arraylist.getindexof(name),  is work but the way is not right, i want to use UserInfo class, Thanks

Comment: You can't really use 'userInfo class' because you need to search it through an instance of arraylist.  You can't find a value when you have nowhere to search in.